# Do we have sorting and searching function in .net

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, collections, search

I was implementing linear search for search in a collection then i thought why not use binary search, for which i had to use sorting. 
Although I can implement them, but I would like to know where does they exists in .net itself. I hope it would be present in .Net.

Comment: Must remember to vote this up when I get more votes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET has sorting implemented by default, but while you can specify the order in which you would like your elements sorted, you cannot specify the algorithm with which it sorts.

As such, you might be interested in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/cssorters.aspx) which provides .NET code for abstractly sorting including implementations of every major sorting method.

Comment: Article given by you seems to be good and very usefull, will comment more after reading and implementing it.

Answer (score 4):

If I didn't get it wrong this is something you are looking for

```
public class Person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;

    public Person(int age, string name)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}


List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

people.Add(new Person(50, "Fred"));
people.Add(new Person(30, "John"));
people.Add(new Person(26, "Andrew"));
people.Add(new Person(24, "Xavier"));
people.Add(new Person(5, "Mark"));
people.Add(new Person(6, "Cameron"));
```

For Searching

```
 // with delegate
    List<Person> young = people.FindAll(delegate(Person p) { return p.age < 25; });

    // with lammda
    List<Person> young = people.FindAll(a=> a.age < 25);
```

For Sorting

```
// with delegate
people.Sort(delegate(TestKlasse a, TestKlasse b) { return a.age.CompareTo(b.age); });

// with lambda function
people.Sort((a, b) => a.age.CompareTo(b.age));
```

Comment: What function does CompareTo uses internally. i.e sorting algo ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be what he's looking for. He is capable of searching, but wants to control the search algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961630/which-sorting-algorithm-is-used-in-stl-and-net-base-library-default-search/961646#961646) SO answer:

> .NET uses a variation of Quicksort (Sedgewick's median of 3 Quicksort).